# How to get position in horizontal scroll view

Tags: android, horizontalscrollview

I am using custom Horizontal scrollView. I have added some views to it all works fine as expected,I want to know the particular child position. Is this possible ?

Comment: you have added view dynamically?

Comment: yes, based on the arraylist size my view will get update

Comment: so you want to know which child number is called right?

Comment: yes, i need to fetch information from the arraylist based on this position.

Comment: than directly add click listener in your for loop for that view

Comment: you can use yourView.setTag("position") in loop, and onclick just get view.getTag().toString().

Comment: yup i added click listener, but which out knowing the clicked item position how can i able to retrieve data from list

Comment: check my answer for more info

Comment: thank you, i am trying your suggestion, let me know you shortly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your loop where you have created your view just add this line :

```
 youView.setTag("your incremental variable");
 youView.setOnClickListener(this);
```

and in onclick(View v) you can get that position by

```
 v.getTag().toString()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code to find the X and Y Position of a particular child of horizontal ScrollView.

```
horizontalScrollView.getChildAt(i).getX();
horizontalScrollView.getChildAt(i).getY();
```